# Can't compile a simple JFACE program; java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, compiler-errors, swt, classpath, jface

I am trying to run a very simple JFace program:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.window.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class HelloSWT_JFace extends ApplicationWindow{

    public HelloSWT_JFace(){
        super(null);
    }
    protected Control createContents(Composite parent){
        Text helloText = new Text(parent, SWT.CENTER);
        helloText.setText("Hello SWT and JFace");
        parent.pack();
        return parent;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloSWT_JFace awin = new HelloSWT_JFace();
        awin.setBlockOnOpen(true);
        awin.open();
        Display.getCurrent().dispose();

    }

}
```

As far as I know, all the libraries are installed and the code, in Eclipse, gives me no errors. Nonetheless, when I run I get

[image: JVM Error]

and the long error report:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Please note; I took a look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952586/cant-use-jface-and-swt-in-eclipse-without-creating-plugin) question and followed the solutions, but installing Equinox plugins did not work.

Comment: Did you add the `org.eclipse.core.runtime<VERSION_NUMBER>.jar` to your project?

Comment: [This](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Identify_the_Required_External_JAR_Files_for_SWT_and_JFace) might help as well.

Comment: Did you verify if the `IProgressMonitor` class is contained in this .jar?

Comment: What do you mean by `verify`?

Comment: I mean: Did you open the jar file and check if the class is contained.

Comment: I don't see it in there, I checked every folder. Should it be?

Comment: I thought you resolved this issue. If it's working now, don't worry about that specific class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the links Baz provided, I found the solution by making sure all the necessary Jars were added (I was missing a couple).

The necessary jars are:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.jface_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.ui.workbench_<version info>.jar
```

More info can be found at the link Baz provided:  ["Identify the Required External JAR Files for SWT and JFace"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Identify_the_Required_External_JAR_Files_for_SWT_and_JFace)

Comment: Isn't that *exactly* the list of jars from the link I posted?

Comment: Yes it is EXACTLY it, and that's why I specified EXACTLY who provided it. Was that your downvote?

Comment: Don't you think I should provide this answer then, since I posted the link?

Comment: But you didn't and I wanted it to be marked resolved, so I did. If you really want to be the one who posts the response go ahead and I'll mark it as accepted. I explicitly mentioned that the answer came from you in my answer but I understand if you want even more complete credit.

Comment: It's just the way this site works. I didn't storm ahead and post it as an answer right away, because I like to make sure that it's really the solution. Just make a small change to your answer so I can revert the downvote. Just keep in mind that the people helping you like to get the credit they deserve.

Comment: Done. I understand you completely and I believe it's so important to give credit where it's due, which is why I gave you all the credit for the answer. I only "answered" it so it would be marked resolved.